# Prevent Hibernate / Spring from failing when database is unavailable but all data is cached

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I got Hibernate's second-level cache working well on a `JpaRepository` method. I can see that the expected SQL queries are logged the first time, while subsequent calls log no queries, as expected.

However, when I stop the SSH tunnel I use to access the database, as to simulate a database outage, performing the same action again results in the following exception being thrown:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction;
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

How can I configure Hibernate / Ehcache / Spring (Boot) to avoid throwing this exception when all relevant data is cached, and thus no access to the database is required?

For reference, here is what the relevant part of the code looks like (in particular, notice the absence of `@Transactional`):

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  public Something findSomethingById(Long id) {
    return myRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
  }
}
```

```java
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Something, Long> {

  @Override
  @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = CACHEABLE, value = "true"))
  Optional<Something> findById(Long id);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: IIUC,  you don't want spring to pool a new connection from the connection pool, that's not going to happen directly. Whenever a request comes to your server spring will pull a connection from connection pool. At that application will fail, a transaction might require any point in the future, so application always gets the first connection before  calling the service methods, though it depends, where you have used `Transactional` annotation.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, there is no way to make Spring not take a connection from the pool, nor a way to tell it to continue if it could not successfully take one, right? Do you perhaps know of a lower-level, more manual way to handle database connections within Spring?